# Is there a way to maintain a text (comment) file in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I know I could just create a dummy module and stick all my comments in there

```
void do_nothing() {return;}  
  // Lots of comments here  
  // More comments here ....
```

But I'd like to have just a plane old text file in each of my Eclipse projects to ,track personal notes on the project. Stuff that dosen't belong in the final project
 - **Like OR Example** -
. Still need spec for SomeSmallPart of project from Sally, it was promised to me 2 weeks ago.
. 2/4/11 Dave said he found bug with the text handling, but he can't duplicate it. Need to see him.
. Remember I'm (suppose to be on) vacation from April 1st to April 10th

That kind of stuff. Is there something I'm missing in eclipse that would just let me have a totally ignored, plain old text file to help me track the world spining around a specific project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um... right-click project or folder -> New -> File, enter filename with .txt extension?

But it sounds like you should instead be using Eclipse's tasks, since those can be sorted, filtered, prioritized, and attached to a specific location in a source code file.

For even more powerful features, take a look at [Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/).